# type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, redux

I am using (I think) an "index access parameter" to write to an object in my reducer:

```js
export type SettingsState = {
    brainRadiusEstimate: number,
    displayProgressIndicator: boolean,
    respiratoryFilterUpperBound: string,
    patientFeedback: PatientFeedbackType,
    connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus,
    brainSize: BrainSize,
    version: 'BETA 2',
}

export type ChangeParameterAction = {
    type: 'CHANGE_PARAMETER',
    parameter: ParameterName,
    value: any
}


export default function settingsReducer(state: SettingsState = defaultState, action: ChangeParameterAction): SettingsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_PARAMETER':
      const newState: SettingsState = { ...state };
      newState[action.parameter] = action.value;
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error on `newState[action.parameter] = action.value` that says "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'".

I see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/) (under "Fixes to unsound writes to indexed access types") that this is indeed to be expected in TypeScript. It says the solution is "If you are convinced that you are not dealing with an error, you can use a type assertion instead."

I've tried adding

```
type ValueTypes = number | string | boolean | null | PatientFeedbackType | ConnectionStatus | BrainSize | 'BETA 2
```

and changing the line to

```
newState[action.parameter] = action.value as ValueTypes;
```

as well as

```
const value: ValueTypes = action.value
newState[action.parameter] = value;
```

but I get the same error, simply with a different type that's not assignable to never.

Is there a way to do this parameter access without simply using `@ts-ignore`?

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] where someone can drop it into an IDE and see the issue you're seeing.  There are a lot of undeclared types in there.  My *guess* is that you could fix this with `(newState as any)[action.parameter] = action.value` but I can't verify that without a reprex.  Good luck!

Comment: What's the definition of `ParameterName`?

Comment: `brainRadiusEstimate` is a great property name, btw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) on the type. But! It's okay, because there's another way to skin this cat: A computed property name:

```
const newState: SettingsState = { ...state, [action.parameter]: action.value };
```

Depending on the definition of `ParameterName`, that should correct the problem. For instance, if `ParameterName` is `keyof SettingsState`, it will.

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnGwCGxoF4oBvAKCnKgCMAnbFAJWwBNEBXdAUXSQFtcIAXFGSselCNQA0ZCi3RgANthAAFagHtU1COnQBJZCwDGuddSGV16hRGzJpFKNvmJawMyABiiBXmoBVMEhqACF1VkMhbmoUVAcKAHoAKhlyMFxECGRgTwgIJkpsIwBrIRUMrJy8gqLigBVwCHjyI3VkZAgjJDasXHYhAGE2jq7EHpxgdmaqWhQYRAAvQSgQ2eR5pemkhNSoADcJdDHkIQByEI46gEEoACZT6QBfEhJQSChy2h54CQA5bG+UEIxQgIHUADNYPAkGhMBMIABuF5vaADAAWdlQEE+AJ+1CuozaQOIuxRZwGAAkrr8AOIcAD6Kiu9CuAFlLhx6A9dukvniytg+X5-t9pntsApWMs7CASM8XhAAB5gMzAKBMCDg7CsXxQcERQnIKDoaGxdD0fKsIwSAAU3H4QjgCDNvTwxI1Wp1wFdTSgRW6Jyg6Mx2MFuL8BIDAEpHabYT6SeR0AB3RDAIxoqA2-3HAB0KKjiYoJhNUFOlOpdMZzLZHK5Al2LTa3GEEGTPtjzvj8OJpEcjlzg-teGmjgA2jm2rneeGJABdIST5C58WSiCNqCPJH9pzwVjUI0ddvw7eyTXa3wNnfaSYH40nmTPR5AA) (using `type ParameterName = keyof SettingsState;`)

Answer (score 12):

In my case the error:

> type **'any'** is not assignable to type **'never'**

Was simply being caused due to an array that was not properly declared (with a specific type). Therefore, I solved it by changing its declaration, e.g. from:

```
myArray: [];
```

To:

```
myArray: any[];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const [array, setArray] = useState<any>([])
```